# Enable loadbalance option in JDBC connection to Vertica (in R)

Tags: r, jdbc, vertica

How can I enable the loadbalancing option in my JDBC connection to Vertica please?
I found out how to do it in ODBC in windows (in ODBC Data Source Administrator) but can't find a way to configure it with a JDBC connection.
I am developing functions to query Vertica from R with a function like that :

vertica_co <<- dbConnect(driver,"jdbc:vertica://url:port/table",user,password)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either set it in your property file as myProp.put("ConnectionLoadBalance", 1);

or in the connection string as

"jdbc:vertica://v_vmart_node0001.example.com:5433/vmart?ConnectionLoadBalance=1"

Make sure you also enable the load balancing policy on the server side as well.